# Stuck at "Your consent screen is being verified"

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I have recently created a project using the youtube data api v3. As the project uses sensitive scopes:

- ../auth/youtube
- ../auth/youtube.force-ssl

I have submitted the oauth consent screen for review. The review team that told me that there is no need to review the project.

Since then (2 months ago) the project is stuck at "Your consent screen is being verified. This may take up to several days. Your last approved consent screen is still in use.".

I am unable to resubmit the project at this point. Users will see the app as "unsecure" as it has not passed review yet.

Has anyone else experienced this before? Is there any way to get in touch with google if you are not on an payed support plan?